# how to use Nested Case with multiple condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

How to modify the below sql script to calculate following condition

- *Total_Inc_Tax* will be *qty* x *unit_price* with 5% when the Issue_date between 1-Jan-2018 and 31-Mar-2018 if LPO NULL or not
- After 31-Mar-2018 when LPO not NULL shouldn't add 5 % with *qty* x *unit_price* other wise add 5%.

  How it works with nested case or suggest any other way.

**My_Table:**

```
+------------+-----+------------+---------------+
| Issue_date | qty | unit_price |      LPO      |
+------------+-----+------------+---------------+
| 10-Jan-18  |   1 |         42 | 1-2018-001166 |
| 12-Jan-18  |   1 |        100 | NULL          |
| 20-Sep-18  |   1 |         25 | NULL          |
| 15-Oct-18  |   2 |         12 | 1-2018-002233 |
| 20-Oct-18  |   1 |        100 | 1-2018-002233 |
+------------+-----+------------+---------------+

SELECT Qty,unit_price,LPO,
    case
    when issue_date <= '2018-03-31'  and issue_date >= '2018-01-01'  
    then (((qty) *(unit_price))  * 1.05 )      
    else    
    (((qty) *(unit_price))  * 1.05 )
    end   as Tot_inc_Tax
    from  My_Table
```

**Expected Result**

```
+------------+-----+------------+---------------+---------------+
| Issue_date | qty | unit_price |      LPO      | Total_Inc_Tax |
+------------+-----+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 10-Jan-18  |   1 |         42 | 1-2018-001166 |          44.1 |
| 12-Jan-18  |   1 |        100 | NULL          |           105 |
| 20-Sep-18  |   1 |         25 | NULL          |         26.25 |
| 15-Oct-18  |   2 |         12 | 1-2018-002233 |            24 |
| 20-Oct-18  |   1 |        100 | 1-2018-002233 |           100 |
+------------+-----+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

From your logic you can try this

1. first one use `OR`
2. second one use `AND`

And make sure all is match with your logic.

```
SELECT Issue_date,Qty,unit_price,LPO,
    case
    when (issue_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-06-30') OR unit_price IS NULL 
      THEN qty *LPO  * 1.05       
    when issue_date > '2018-03-31' AND unit_price IS NOT NULL 
      THEN qty * LPO  END 'Total_Inc_Tax'
from  My_Table
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee8246c0fb6f3884b9753a39a32441eb)

Comment: need to replace qty * LPO with  qty *unit_price  and ( OR LPO IS NULL )

Answer (score 1):

One calculation option would be :

```
with my_table(Issue_date, qty, unit_price, LPO) as  
(
 select '2018-01-10',1,42 ,'1-2018-001166' union all
 select '2018-01-12',1,100,NULL            union all
 select '2018-09-20',1,25 ,NULL            union all
 select '2018-10-15',2,12 ,'1-2018-002233' union all
 select '2018-10-20',1,100,'1-2018-002233'     
)
select Qty,unit_price,LPO,
       (case
          when issue_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-31'  
            then (((qty) *(unit_price))  * 1.05 )      
          when issue_date > '2018-03-31' then
          ( case when lpo is null then
                 (((qty) *(unit_price))  * 1.05 )
            else
                 (((qty) *(unit_price))) 
            end )
        end ) as Tot_inc_Tax
  from  My_Table;
```

[***dbfiddle demo***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fa0467285b71ec2fddbc022022f4c720)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
SELECT Qty,unit_price,LPO,
case
when issue_date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-03-31'  
then (((qty) *(unit_price))  * 1.05 )      
else   when  issue_date > '2018-03-31' and LPO is null
(((qty) *(unit_price))  * 1.05 )
end   as Tot_inc_Tax
from  My_Table
```